# Prove that the set is subspace of $P_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

${P_3}\ (R)  :
$$
 \{ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d \ \ | \ \ a + b + c + d = 0\}
$
For this type of situation, is there a way to choose values ​​to prove that it is a subspace or is it necessary to use generalizing vectors? Example :

$$
\displaylines{{\vec V1  = a_1x^3 + b_1x^2 + c_1x + d_1} \\ \vec V2 = a_2x^3 + b_2x^2 + c_2x + d_2 
\\ a_1x^3 + b_1x^2 + c_1x + d_1 = 0 \ \\ a_2x^3 + b_2x^2 + c_2x + d_2 = 0 }
$$

Comment: Your question needs more context. Any subspace $U$ is a subset of a vector space $V$. What vector space $V$ are you working in?

Comment: Sorry. 
I want to prove whether or not it is a subspace of $P_3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of ways you can show that. I'll write here what I thought.

You can try to find some polynomials $p,q,r,...$ such that the subspace generated by them is equal to $S := \{ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d | a + b + c + d = 0\}$, but I think there's no trivial way to find these guys (I thought a little bit and didn't come up
with anything).

I believe the simplest way to prove this is using the definition of subspace: taking two general polynomials in S and proving that their sum is in S and do the same for scalar multiplication. It's not a difficult argument. If you have any problems doing that, we can chat in the comments.

A "more advanced" way is showing that $S$ is the kernel of a certain linear functional in $P_3$, since kernels are always subspaces.

Comment: I was looking for a shortcut to using values. But I did it this way:
$$
\displaylines{{\vec V1  = a_1x^3 + b_1x^2 + c_1x + d_1} \\ \vec V2 = a_2x^3 + b_2x^2 + c_2x + d_2 
\\ a_1x^3 + b_1x^2 + c_1x + d_1 = 0 \ \\ a_2x^3 + b_2x^2 + c_2x + d_2 = 0 
\\ \vec V1 + \vec V2 = (a_1x^3 + b_1x^2 + c_1x + d_1) + (a_2x^3 + b_2x^2 + c_2x + d_2) 
\\ \vec V1 + \vec V2 = (0) + (0) => \vec V1 + \vec V2 = 0
\\
\\ α \in R. \\ α \vec V1 = α(a_1x^3 + b_1x^2 + c_1x + d_1)
\\  α \vec V1 = α(0)  }
$$

Comment: Your idea is good, but what you wrote is not entirely right. Notice that the set is
$$ 
\{ ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d : a + b + c + d = 0\} 
$$
and **not**
$$
\{ ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d : ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = 0\}.
$$

Notice that the first set has polynomials different from zero. For example: $x^3 - x^2$ ($a = 1, b = -1, c = d = 0), 3x^3 - 3/2x - 3/2 (a = 3, b = 0, c = -3/2, d= - 3/2$. The second one has only the polynomial with all coefficients zero.

Comment: I really got confused when performing the calculations.

I got stuck in the penultimate equation. I jumped to the last equation that I believe would be the last phase of the calculations.

Comment: $$
\displaylines{{\vec V1  = a_1x^3 + b_1x^2 + c_1x + d_1} \\ \vec V2 = a_2x^3 + b_2x^2 + c_2x + d_2 
\\ a_1+ b_1 + c_1 + d_1 = 0 \ \\ a_ 2+ b_2 + c_2 + d_2 = 0
\\ \vec V1 + \vec V2 = \bigl ((a_1x^3 + b_1x^2 + c_1x + d_1) + (a_2x^3 + b_2x^2 + c_2x + d_2) \bigr) 
\\ \vec V1 + \vec V2 = \bigl ((a_1+a_2)x^3 + (b_1+b_2)x^2 + (c_1 + c_2)x + (d_1 + d_2) \bigr)
\\ \vec V1 + \vec V2 = \bigl ((a_1+ b_1 + c_1 + d_1) + (a_2+ b_2 + c_2 + d_2) \bigr)}
$$

Comment: Exactly! The penultimate equation is correct, now considering
\begin{align*}
a = a_1 + a_2 \\
b = b_1 + b_2 \\
c = c_1 + c_2 \\
d = d_1 + d_2 \\
\end{align*}
what can you say about $a + b + c + d$ ?

Comment: Would a + b + c + d = 0?

I could rewrite this equation in this format: $$
\displaylines{ 
\\ \vec V1 + \vec V2 = \bigl ((a_1+a_2)x^3 + (b_1+b_2)x^2 + (c_1 + c_2)x + (d_1 + d_2) \bigr)
\\ \vec V1 + \vec V2 = \bigl ((a)x^3 + (b)x^2 + (c)x + d )\bigr)}
$$

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Notice that 
\begin{align*}
(a_1 + a_2) + (b_1 + b_2) + (c_1 + c_2) + (d_1 + d_2) = \\
= (a_1 + b_1 + c_1 + d_1) + (a_2 + b_2 + c_2 + d_2) = 0 + 0 = 0 \\
\end{align*}

Comment: I could extrapolate this way to scale it:$$
\displaylines{ 
\\ α  \vec V1 = α\bigl ((a_1)x^3 + (b_1)x^2 + (c_1)x + (d_1) \bigr)
\\ N\ o \ t \ e \ : αax^3 + αbx^2 + αcx + αd = 0
\\=> α(ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d) = 0
\\ α\vec V1 = α\bigl ((a_1)x^3 + (b_1)x^2 + (c_1)x + (d_1) \bigr) = 0)
}
$$

Comment: Be careful with notation. The equation
$$
\overrightarrow{V} = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = 0 
$$
means that the polinomial $ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ is the zero vector (the polynomial with all coefficients zero). Now, the equation
$$
a + b + c + d = 0
$$
means that the sum of these four real numbers is zero.

Comment: So, given a scalar $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\overrightarrow{V} = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ such that $a + b + c + d = 0$, we have 
$$
\alpha \overrightarrow{V} = \alpha a x^3 + \alpha b x^2 + \alpha c x + \alpha d
$$
and notice that 
$$
\alpha a + \alpha b + \alpha c + \alpha d = \alpha (a + b + c + d) = \alpha \cdot 0 = 0
$$
so the vector $\alpha \overrightarrow{V}$ is in the same space as $\overrightarrow{V}$, because the sum of its coefficients is zero.